# Add user to YouTube Partner CMS - API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Does anyone know where in the content partner api we can find the code to add a user to the YouTube CMS. Or if this is even possible?

Answer (score -1):

If it existed, it would be listed in [the API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/). As far as I know, the only way to add users is by inviting them from CMS.